# Which cell balancing method is best to use and implement for low-voltage (48V battery stack) battery management system for E-bike application?

Tags: battery-charging, circuit-design, embedded, automotive, battery-balance

I would like to design a battery management system for low voltage systems. I am developing a BMS for a **48V, 20Ah** battery pack system.

When it comes to battery balancing, I am confused in between resistor based passive and capacitor based active cell balancing method.  Which one is better for my low voltage system application?

**Passive cell balancing:**
Shunt resistor method: It bleeds the charge through resistors and transistor switch, but the energy is wasted through a resistor as heat.  Even though it is a low voltage battery pack my confusion is will this heat increase the temperature and will this be a problem?

**Active cell balancing:**
Switched capacitor cell balancing in this method the battery is getting balanced by transferring the charge from high voltage cell to low voltage cells by using capacitor and transistor switch. It is more efficient than passive cell balancing but it takes more time to get equalized and it depends on large voltage variation.

Other cell balancing methods like inductor or transformer based and converter based are more efficient but more complex and expensive for low voltage BMS and as a beginner.

So I am confused as to which cell balancing method is best for a low voltage (48V, 20Ah) system.
Please suggest to me which method is best to use based on my requirements.

Comment: Even if 48V is relatively low voltage, **it still is dangerous**. And lithium batteries will catch on fire if not maintained correctly. Thus, if you consider yourself a beginner, I **highly** suggest you buy a ready-made BMS circuit, rather than creating your own BMS. BMS at 48V are readily available at very low prices nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise on going with a passive balancing strategy if you are to doing it yourself. And I would advise on that for four reasons:

1. It is much easier to adjust the charging rate of your battery since you can close loop regulate the charging current with respect to the temperature of your balancing resistors. You can thus minimize your charge time by being on the edge (with a safety margin) of over-heating. This is assuming your cells are really crap, thus making balancing power dissipation your limiting factor. In my experience I have never reached the point were the heat from balancing was a problem, when working within the manufacturers recommended maximum charging current. Buy good quality cells to begin with.
2. Many BMS board that exist off the shelves use this balancing strategy, for which the only drawback is from an efficiency standpoint. And even though there is a slight increase in efficiency, you will only notice a difference if your cells get vastly out of balance. Again buy good quality cells to begin with.
3. The regulation scheme and mostly the switching aspect of it is dead simple to implement: (from the cell perspective) "Is my voltage higher than the lowest cell in the pack (+- hysteresis) ?  Yes, discharge. No, do nothing.
4. There exists open-source projects that you can inspire yourself from, that all utilize this balancing scheme, which will make your probability of making something that works much greater :

https://github.com/Teslafly/OpenBMS

https://github.com/foxBMS/foxbms

https://github.com/DieBieEngineering/DieBieMS

https://github.com/EnnoidMe/ENNOID-BMS

If capacitor shuttling strategies were vastly better overall, one of thos smart engineer from these 4 projects would have implmented it this way. Also it is most likely cheaper since chinese manufacturers of 48V batteries all use resistive balancing strategies.

Be careful. Keep a bucket of dry sand around. Or something that would prevent burning down your lab in the event of a short-circuited cell(s).